# If you could recommend only one blog on software testing, which one would it be?

Tags: testing, blogs

I found a question here about blogs on software development, but I would like to know which blogs on software testing this community reads.

If you just have to recommend more than one blog, post each one in separate answer, so others can vote on specific blog. :)

Thanks!

**Edit:** I am not interested in sites that aggregate other blogs, because as @Alan said (in his answer) there are both good and not so good blogs there.

Comment: [http://www.testingreflections.com/](http://www.testingreflections.com/) [http://testingsoftware.blogspot.com/](http://testingsoftware.blogspot.com/)

Comment: I see I was not clear enough. I will edit the question. I am not interested in sites that aggregate other blogs, because as @Alan said there are both good and not so good blogs there.

Also, please add only one blog per answer so people can vote for each blog separately. :)

Comment: [http://randallrice.blogspot.com/](http://randallrice.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/alanpa), of course, is quite interesting - but will not be to everyone. TestingReflections is nice because it aggregates a bunch of random test blogs, but the problem is that it aggregates the bad with the good. Many of the posts that make it to the site don't have much use.

It also depends on what you're looking for - are you looking for a blog on testing philosophy, one about functional test techniques, something about writing automated tests, something all-encompassing, or something different?

Comment: I was reading your blog, but since my time for reading blogs decreased, I had to delete it from my feed reader (with a tear in the eye). :)

I am looking at a blog that a tester (that does not have a lot of time) can read and get better after each post he reads. So, something general I guess.

Comment: late getting back here, but blog.abakas.com may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

[Abakas](http://blog.abakas.com). It's written by my boss, but I'd recommend it even if that weren't the case.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Testing Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I was reading that too, but I will take another look.

Answer (score 2):

James Bach at http://www.satisfice.com/blog/ . Very good.

Answer (score -1):

For Russian-speaking community is definitely:

http://it4business.ru/forum/index.php?showforum=192

But I think everybody knows that :)

Comment: This looks like forum, not blog. Or is it just me?